# How to add symbols on edges to say they are same length?

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are some edges having the same length. I want to add little symbol on it as in the picture:

[image: same length at DA, DB, DC]

How do I do? Thanks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}      
\coordinate (Base1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (Base2) at (4,0);
\coordinate (Base3) at (5,2);
\coordinate (TopPt) at (2,5);
\draw [draw=black, every edge/.append style={draw=black, dashed}]
     (Base1) -- (Base2) --(Base3) 
     (Base3) edge (Base1);
\draw [draw=black, every edge/.append style={draw=black, dashed}]
     (TopPt) -- (Base1) 
     (TopPt) -- (Base2) 
     (TopPt) -- (Base3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place a node on the line an have it align with the slope of the line by using `sloped`.  For the double line I used the `\parallel` symbol.  If don't like the symbol being orthogonal to the line, add some slight tilting by a adding `rotate=<angle>` to the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (Base1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (Base2) at (4,0);
\coordinate (Base3) at (5,2);
\coordinate (TopPt) at (2,5);
\draw [draw=black, every edge/.append style={draw=black, dashed}]
     (Base1) -- (Base2) -- (Base3) 
     (Base3) edge (Base1);
\draw [draw=black, every edge/.append style={draw=black, dashed}]
     (TopPt) -- node[sloped] {$\parallel$} (Base1) 
     (TopPt) -- node[sloped] {$\parallel$} (Base2) 
     (TopPt) -- node[sloped] {$\parallel$} (Base3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]